# Symfony2 Forms : Changing the default prefix in Form Labels

Tags: forms, symfony

I am rendering a form, and every widget has an ID like : form_username, form_password, etc
and every corresponding label has a **for** field as for="form_username"

can I customize this ID and For attribute pair? Because I am rendering 2 forms on a page, and their field names are clashing...

**edit** : Here is an example code where I want to customize the Form Name.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user, array('validation_groups' => array('registration')))
             ->add('username', 'text')
             ->add('email', 'email')
             ->add('password', 'repeated', array('type' => 'password'))
             ->getform();
```

Comment: Are you using a form class, or the FormBuilder from the controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide different names for the forms when you create them in your controller:

```
$builder1 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(new FooFormType(), 'foo1');
$builder2 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder(new FooFormType(), 'foo2');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i hadn't specified the question fully...

I'm using the FormBuilder one, so i don't think this solution would work.

Comment: His answer is correct, $this->createFormBuilder() is just a shortcut to same service call. Just try it.

Comment: @kris : I am getting an error like : Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::createFormBuilder() must be an array, string given when I am supplying an additional argument to the createFormBuilder() function.

Comment: That's not the correct method. You need to call `$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder()`

Comment: Thanks Kris. It is a pain navigating through the sparse documentation on sf-2.0, but finally I could spot the correct usage from the source code. I was thinking if I could have used createFormBuilder(), but it has no parameter for accepting a custom Form name.